# When to write user input to the database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

Newer developer here. I'm creating a Nodejs application with MongoDB. When do you write user inputs to the database? Is it immediately when they want to perform a CRUD action? Or do you wait until they end their session to update their changes (showing them a "fake" updated view during the meantime)? I would think writing to the database every time would be less than ideal, but I also wouldn't want to make the user think their changes were saved to the database, and then some error occurs where it didn't actually happen. How's this handled in the real world?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user inputs should be written to the database as soon as the user wants to perform the CRUD operations.

If they are not, and you wait for the user to terminate their session, there may be other parts of the application that try and change the data that was supposed to be updated. Or you may want to take certain action in your application based on the current user data from the database, but your database reflects older data, and your application may behave incorrectly.

One may argue that you can maintain the `current state` of your application, but in case of backend code, the database should always be your single source of thruth.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's known in the "real world" (as you referred to) as a **design decision**. It's not something for which there's anything even remotely resembling a rule-of-thumb or a hard-and-fast rule.

Instead, it's important to consider all possible factors relating to this design prior to committing to it:

- **User expectations** - will the users of this application expect that their input is stored *immediately*? When they click the "Save" button? Do they expect their input to be destroyed?
- **Data retention** - are there requirements to retain user input prior to its formal submission? (This is useful in applications for which
- **Infrastructure** - can the underlying infrastructure handle the increased workload? When this application is scaled, will the infrastructure demands exceed capacity?
- **Cost/benefit** - will the addition of this feature trigger development/testing times that exceed acceptable levels for the benefit the feature provides?

These are just *some* of the considerations you might have. I'm sure with additional time most people could come up with at least ten more.